# How do I extract this data that I want in R?

Tags: r

I have a data called "test"

```
   dput(test)>
   structure(list(Data = c("Apple", "3", "Orange", "4", "Grape", 
   "2", "Orange", "5", "Grape", "1", "Orange", "4")), class = c("tbl_df", 
   "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

I wish to extract the "Orange" number. How do I do that if all my data is in one column.

My desire output is

```
 Data  

 Orange1
  4         
 Orange2
  5     
 Orange3
  4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr` library:

```
library(dplyr)

test%>% filter(Data == "Orange" | lag(Data)=="Orange")
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 1
  Data  
  <chr> 
1 Orange
2 4     
3 Orange
4 5     
5 Orange
6 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Base R

```
test$Data[which(test$Data=="Orange")+1]
[1] "4" "5" "4"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R answer:

```r
dat <- structure(list(Data = c("Apple", "3", "Orange", "4", "Grape", 
                        "2", "Orange", "5", "Grape", "1", "Orange", "4")), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                     "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L))

dat$Data[which(dat$Data == "Orange")+1]
#> [1] "4" "5" "4"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>